# Is a Spring Bean always a POJO?

Tags: java, spring, pojo, spring-bean

Is it necessary that a Spring Bean always has to be a POJO?

Are there any other ways to create a bean which is not a POJO?

Comment: What else do you expect to be?

Comment: I don't know yet, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: POJO = plain old java object, so any class is a POJO. Spring intends to not impose special structure on code.

Comment: What is a POJO? As opposed to other objects whose class...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Spring bean can be anything. Classes that can be instantiated normally (i.e. Java Beans or any other regular class) can be configured via xml or Java-Config.

Anything that is more complicated can be created via a [FactoryBean](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean).

So, to answer your question: Any Java object can become a Spring Bean.

Answer (score 2):

I think that there is a misunderstanding.
POJO means Plain Old Java Object. 
It refers to a Java object that isn't bogged down by framework extensions.

We associate Spring with POJO to express that with Spring, the beans stay simple, testable, adaptable, etc..., not or rather few coupled to specific framework interfaces or implementations.
POJO brings a low coupling by using generally metadata such as XML or code annotations (often preferred as less verbose and located directly in the concerning class) to bind the beans to the framework.

POJO may be opposed to intrusive frameworks as EJB 2.X that creates a strong coupling between beans and the EJB framework.

Now, your beans may be POJO or not.
Of course, the first way should be promoted for explained reasons.
And by using Spring, you generally have no reason to not use exclusively POJO classes for your beans as POJO are better and Spring generally doesn't force you to couple your bean classes to some specific Spring classes or interfaces.
Note that you have some cases where we have to couple to Spring framework  classes in your bean classes as you want to benefit from Spring features enhancement such as Spring `Repository`.
But in these cases, you get "more" than a bean.